# How to set logging level for different packages in simplelogger.properties for SLF4J-simple

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

In simplelogger.properties file we can set default logging level as

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=error
```

but If one wants to set logging level for specific package then how to do that?
For example If the package name is

> com.xxx.yyy

then If I put it in simplelogger.properties as

```
com.xxx.yyy.level=error
```

then it does not work. 
How to configure it?

Comment: Why is this tagged log4j? Are you using simplelogger, log4j, or somehow both?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The SLF4J SimpleLogger has all [its documentation in its Javadoc](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html).

As it says,

> `org.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.a.b.c` - Logging detail level for a SimpleLogger instance named "a.b.c". Right-side value must be one of "trace", "debug", "info", "warn", "error" or "off". When a SimpleLogger named "a.b.c" is initialized, its level is assigned from this property. If unspecified, the level of nearest parent logger will be used, and if none is set, then the value specified by `org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel` will be used.

So you need to include a line like this in your simplelogger.properties:

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.com.xxx.yyy=error
```

If you start needing a more complex logging system than the SLF4J SimpleLogger, then you probably want to switch to using something like Log4j or Logback.

Answer (score 0):

For setting level on your own package use different file [per logging implementation](http://www.luyue.org/configure-slf4j-working-various-logging-frameworks/)

> **Configure SLF4J working with Java Logger**
>
> configure JDK logging either by editing JRE_DIRECTORY/lib/logging.properties
>
> **Configure SLF4J working with Log4J**
>
> add a configuration file such as src/main/resources/log4j.properties.
>
> **Configure SLF4J working with Logback**
>
> add a configuration file such as src/main/resources/logback.xml